# Adobe Sign - No Cloud

Tags: browser, adobe, signature

Our company is looking for a solution with a particular workflow and I'm wondering if Adobe Sign (or another product they have) has the capabilities, say via API, to:

1. Display a document (PDF) in a web browser (but with the document created real-time on the server then displayed/served in browser for signing).
2. Allow the user to mark up the PDF (sign, mark checkboxes, etc...)
3. Save the document to a non-adobe server (streaming the signed version back to the original server) for saving in a proprietary system.

Would anyone know if this is possible or a direction for which I might look?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Sign is an advanced solution to automate contract signing workflows. It does offers all the capabilities you mentioned in a very intuitive and easy. Please find below the API based solutions using which you can meet your requirements -

- Display a document (PDF) in a web browser (but with the document
  created real-time on the server then displayed/served in browser for
  signing).

  > > You can use [POST /agreements](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/agreements/createAgreement) API which will allow you to create an agreement in real time by mentioning the relevant details like participants, documents, agreement name etc. Once the agreement is created you will get back an agreementId in the response. Use this returned agreementId to make a call to [GET /signingUrls](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/agreements/getSigningUrl) which will allow you to fetch the Signing URL of the agreement for current signer. Use this URL and render it in browser to perform Signing on the agreement
- Allow the user to mark up the PDF (sign, mark checkboxes, etc..)

  > > Adobe Sign APIs allows you to author a document with form fields like custom Signing fields, text fields, checkboxes etc.
  > >     There are multiple ways to author a document using APIs - 
  > >     **Authoring APIs** : Create an agreement in Authoring state via POST /agreements API and then use [PUT /formFields](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/agreements/updateFormFields) API to author the agreement with specific fields.
  > >     **Library templates** : You can create a library document of DOCUMENT_TEMPLATE type(either via API or web) with all the form fields that you want place on the agreement. Pass the ID of this created library template in formFieldLayerTemplates attribute during agreement creation via POST /agreement API to apply those fields onto the agreement.
  > >     **Text tags** : You can put the form fields on a document by putting the textual representation of the fields in the syntax defined [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/sign/help/adobesign_text_tag_guide.html). Use this document to create an agreement and Adobe Sign will parse those text tags and convert those textually represented fields into actual fields
  > >     Once these fields are applied on the document, the signer whom that specific field is assigner would be able to fill it up on the Signing page.
- Save the document to a non-adobe server (streaming the signed
  version back to the original server) for saving in a proprietary
  system.

  > > Adobe Sign has a concept of Vaulting which you can enable for your account. Once enabled you can configure this vaulting per agreement via POST /agreements. For a vaulting enabled agreement Sign will ping the vault provider whenever that agreement gets signed. The vault provider can then retrieve the agreement and save it to there servers.